# Python sockets: sending and receving three multi messages at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-3.x, networking

I'm working on a project to send some data from the server to the client, like name, age, and country as a messages to the client from the server.

I created this code using python and socket lib but I want to know are there any better ways to get the messages in the same order?

For example I'm sending a "first message" then "second message" then "third message" so the output should be in the same order: "first message" then "second message" then "third message"

Here is my code:

sending

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
MESSAGE2 = "Hello, world2"
MESSAGE3 = "Hello, world3"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
sock.sendto(MESSAGE2.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
sock.sendto(MESSAGE3.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

receiving

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                    socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:2", data
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:3", data
```

Comment: Consider ZeroMQ (pyzmq). It can make these tasks much simpler.

Comment: You are using UDP which is stateless, there is no sequence on UDP packets unless you add such information to your protocol. If you want reliable sequential message delivery, you use TCP.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using udp use tcp which will make sure that the messages will be in order